# How to update only billing details of active payment method in stripe without adding new payment?

Tags: php, wordpress, stripe-payments

I have WordPress site in which i can create new payment in stripe by passing billing address details like line1, line2, post code etc. and it is working fine for me. when i retrive payment lists i can get all details. However i need to update only billing details of existing payment method.

```
{
   "id":"pm_1KroZ92eZvKYlo2CAalg1J7h",
   "object":"payment_method",
   "billing_details":{
      "address":{
         "city":null,
         "country":null,
         "line1":null,
         "line2":null,
         "postal_code":null,
         "state":null
      },
      "email":null,
      "name":null,
      "phone":null
   },
   "card":{
      "brand":"visa",
      "checks":{
         "address_line1_check":null,
         "address_postal_code_check":null,
         "cvc_check":"unchecked"
      },
      "country":"US",
      "exp_month":8,
      "exp_year":2023,
      "fingerprint":"Xt5EWLLDS7FJjR1c",
      "funding":"credit",
      "generated_from":null,
      "last4":"4242",
      "networks":{
         "available":[
            "visa"
         ],
         "preferred":null
      },
      "three_d_secure_usage":{
         "supported":true
      },
      "wallet":null
   },
   "created":1650741864,
   "customer":"cus_4QE4bx4C5BVSrC",
   "livemode":false,
   "metadata":{
      "order_id":"6735"
   },
   "type":"card"
}
```

I have tried to update address fields via update customer api but it is not working, address of customer has been updated but not reflected into active payment in stripe.
https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update

I have also checked payment intend Api, but can not find any address related parameter in Api request.

I have checked stripe documents but could not find related information for directly update address in existing payment without add card details. Can someone guide me or share me online document / link for update address of existing payment in stripe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's this API : https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/update

Comment: @karllekko thanks for response, but i can not see any address parameter in request, do you have an idea how can i pass billing details in update api ?

Comment: it's the `billing_details[address]` parameter https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/update#update_payment_method-billing_details-address

Comment: @karllekko I have refer above document and could update only address fields of active payment method, thanks a lot !! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is document of stripe in which update only address fields of active payment method

https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/update#update_payment_method-billing_details-address